# How to Connect opc server?

Tags: modbus, opc, modbus-tcp

I have Analyzer which connects to a computer with cat5 cables . This Computer reads the data through a software called ComVisioner .ComVisioner has two Modes, one is Server Mode and Other is  Client Mode A Server software acts as the engine in the system, providing one or more clients with information.

Server version is  installed on a single computer . Once Server version is installed  it collects data, performs calculations, produce reports and so on.

The ComVisioner client runs in the same computer as the server. Other clients can access the same single server through a network, providing that the software license allows more than one client at the same time

so there is Two client computers who access the as mentioned above .this all connection is done by Network cables . This part is fine

As License of Client  is very expensive our company wants to add a OPC software so that more user can acquire data .As i have no knowledge on Opc part please suggest me How can i do it ?. what sort of software should i use ?. Can i install this software different pc with is connected in same network

There is also one more software installed in that computer which pushes the data as Modbus protocol

Comment: In case you are not aware Stackoverflow focuses on computer programming. To be able to answer your question we would need much more information. Nothing much comes up searching for the software you mention, I could not even find anything referring to Modbus or OPC. Being a commercial software it's not even sure you as the owner of the software have that information or are legally able to share it (as it is written, your question seems to imply you want to find a way to bypass the licensing). Conclusion: rework your question if you don't want to see it downvoted or removed.

Comment: i am not talking about by pass licensing , we want to implement a new system of opc software ( looking for best suggestion) which can read data from Analyzer . if you want any data or documents i can provide you

Comment: If your software is able to read from a Modbus TCP slave I think that would be the easiest, if you can add info on that or what kind of OPC it implements I can try to comment, otherwise, I wouldn't know where to start, your question is too broad as it is.

Comment: my software does not read modbus tcp , but my software can push data as modbus rtu . as i research  online i find anybus converter with convert modbus rtu to modbus tcp.  Then we will use kepware (opc software ) to see data is that ok or i need some thing else

Comment: I see. You can use a Modbus RTU to TCP converter or use a serial port directly to read Modbus RTU (you might need an RS485 adaptor though). Once you have Modbus data you can very easily set up a Modbus client or server on your computer with pymodbus, libmodbus, or many more options. If you have kepware licenses you can read Modbus RTU and probably TCP too, see [here](https://www.kepware.com/en-us/products/kepserverex/drivers/modbus-serial/). There is no need of OPC.

Comment: then what about the client , is kepware not a opc ? .i know this is silly question but i really donnot know what is opc

Comment: I don't know what you are planning to do with the data but as far as you have explained I don't think you need OPC. Kepware can do many things and OPC is just a way to exchange data.

Comment: now my question is how client can get data from kepware

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DaIsNfC_3G90cWI0PpNmopYEIXi5Dy-5/view?usp=sharing) is this help

Comment: You should study the features you have on kepware, there are many ways to do that. But my point was you can read data directly from your client computer with any Modbus library

Comment: can you suggest how we get data in opc server format directly computer/ analyzer with out modbus

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, I don't have any documentation of your setup and it would be quite futile. You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/master/README.md) project

Comment: thanks 4 your expertness ....if you tell which document you need i can upload and share link

Comment: You are welcome. Give the examples on the link I posted a go and see if you can make your question a bit more precise so we can answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that the ComVisioner can give OPC data. (work like opc server). This should be indicated in the documentation.

Download the free OPC client, and make sure you can read the data (for example you can use, [matrikon opc explorer](https://www.matrikonopc.com/downloads/176/software/index.aspx) or [kepware quick client](https://www.kepware.com/) (I like it more, it goes together with KepServerEx, to download them you need to register)

If you can connect and see the data, then there will be no problems with access to the data. Next you need to find a solution for which Opc client suits you. Probably some SCADA system, but some good SCADA also cost a lot, and require a lot of development time.

*I don't recommend you try to use modbus if there is opc. If you will use modbus you will have many problem with addressing and value format.*

**ps**
We had a problem with expensive licenses. As a result, we solved the problem by give access for programm for clients via RDP (remote desktop connection)

Comment: ComVisioner can  does not give any opc data , this is our problem  ..it pull data only by modbus  and problem in remote desktop is , only one user can access at one time . is any solution for reading data directly from LD500 LASER DIODE GAS ANALYSER (CEM) . [you can see Sepcification Here] (https://www.opsis.se/en/Products/Products-CEM-Process/LD500-Laser-Diode-Gas-Analyser)